# wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: io, filename) - Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm having a problem with active storage after upgrading rails version to 7.1.2. I am trying to run this code:

```
banner = Banner.new
img_url = "https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/04/75/78/56/360_F_475785604_HDtTcxBFA0Av87F7JoFmpircCcatQ22b.jpg"
picture = URI.open(img_url, {ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE})
banner.img_v2.attach(io: picture, filename: File.basename(picture), key: "banners/v2/#{File.basename(picture)}.png")
banner.save
```

And i am getting following error on `banner.save` or `banner.img_v2.url`:

```
/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activestorage-7.1.2/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:87:in `build_after_unfurling': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: io, filename) (ArgumentError)
```

I found [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37411) issue closest to mine but it didn't help. Appreciate for any help or suggestion.

Comment: I'm going to try to reproduce your issue. Do you mind telling from which version were you upgrading?

Also do you mind upgrading to 7.1.3?

Comment: And the last thing, what is your version of URI gem? When I tried to run your code with version 0.12.1 I encountered an error of calling a private method #open

Comment: I am upgrading from Rails 6.1.3.1 - ruby 2.7.2. And my URI gem version is also 0.12.1, it's working for me. I'll try to upgrade 7.1.3, thanks.

Comment: I have some news, I managed to run this script, it seems like I had to require 'open-uri' gem. The thing is I couldn't reproduce your error. Steps which I have taken:
1. gem uninstall -aIx # to clean all of my gems
2. gem install rails -v 6.1.3.1
3. gem update --system 3.5.5
4. gem install bundler
5. rails new example-old
6. cd example-old
7. rails g model Banner
8. rails active_storage:install
9. added a line with has_one_attached :img_v2 to app/models/banner.rb 

As expected your example works on my environment

(continuation in the next comment)

Comment: (continuation)

Then I checked your example and it worked. Then I updated rails to 7.1.3:
1. Updated rails Gemfile
2. bundle install
3. rails app:update
4. rails db:migrate

Unfortunately the script still works. May I ask you if you're still using ruby 2.7.2?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. Since you couldn't reproduce the error, i tougnt there is a specific situation in my code and figure out i'm using an initializer file which is compatible with rails 6. Then i find out the source code and see someone got the same error as me [here](https://gist.github.com/dinatih/dbfdfd4e84faac4037448a06c9fdc016?permalink_comment_id=3974197#gistcomment-3974197) with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out i was using an initializer for active storage which is compatible with rails 6. I find out the source code and the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/dinatih/dbfdfd4e84faac4037448a06c9fdc016?permalink_comment_id=3974197#gistcomment-3974197).

The error comes from this line:

```
when Hash
  ActiveStorage::Blob.build_after_unfurling({ metadata: { acl: acl } }.deep_merge(attachable))
```

Correction:

```
when Hash
  ActiveStorage::Blob.build_after_unfurling \
    io: attachable[:io],
    filename: attachable[:filename],
    content_type: attachable[:content_type],
    metadata: { acl: acl }
```

Comment: You could just change the original to `ActiveStorage::Blob.build_after_unfurling(**{ metadata: { acl: acl } }.deep_merge(attachable))` which is expand the Hash into kwargs.